# SwiftUI: Kingfisher using KFImage can display erroneous semitransparent image

Tags: swift, swiftui, kingfisher

I am using KFImage to asynchronously load images in SwiftUI views including List rows. 
Sometimes it happens that when scrolling rows and there are I think some cell reusing or refreshes KFImage image displayed is made with a little semitransparency and it stays.
I have such code:

```
KFImage(URL(string: self.host + "/image.png"))
            .resizable()
            .placeholder {
                self.makeInitialsView()
            }
            .cancelOnDisappear(true)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            .clipShape(Circle())
```

I suppose it can be some error in KFImage, but I do not know whether KFImage component or Kingfisher library has such behaviour to display image sometimes with semitransparency for instance to indicate loading image or something else.

it is used in swiftui list like:

```
List { 
  ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item { 
     ItemRow(item: item)
  }
}

ItemRow { 
   var body: some View {

        HStack(alignment: .top) {


            self.makeAvatar()


            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               Text("Some text")
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ....else it is very hard to reproduce...

Comment: It is minimal reproducible. I have row and there is image loading code like this. with KFImage from Kingfisher. usually it loads ok given images. sometimes it while scrolling list it loads/displays this image with semitransparency overlay? or alpha set ot 0.5?

Comment: no it is not. can i copy and run your code ? no.

Comment: I've added use case. I've added snippet causing problem i.e. image loading from Kingfisher. I think it is useless to copy paste all unrelated code to the problem like rows layouts custom core data models fetch request that doesn't have anything to do with error